# How to add a confirming pop up window in objective?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

like JOptionPane in java,
when user do something.
and i ask for confirmation like,
are you sure you want to delete file?? or whatever the case is.
user confirms it
then i detect what user has chosen between both buttons
then i do something according to user choice

is there anything like this in objective c ??
links plz and some guidelines

thank you every one

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for UIAlertView controller.

Comment: Alert view isn't really a controller, just a view, but it is indeed what he is looking for

Comment: yes i have tried them
but they are not working for detecting what user tapped

Comment: No,  you should be using UIActionSheet.

Comment: actualy you can use both 
but the UIActionSheet have the advantage to color the destructive button in red.
In both case you'll have to know that those are asynchronous, so when the popup appear, the app continue to run. You must use a
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
or something equivalent.
I think you have all the necessary key words now ;)

@Dan F : thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is what Apple Recommends for user choice:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"button To Destroy or nil" otherButtonTitles:@"Choice 1", @"Choice 2", @"Choice 3", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check which button is being clicked under `otherButtonTitles:`

Something like this:

```
UIAlertView *yourAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title" message:@"Some String" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm",nil];  

 [yourAlert show];
```

And remember to set the delegate to self.

Then:

> ```
> - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
>
> if (buttonIndex == 0){
>
>     //'Dismissing' code here
>
> }
>
> if (buttonIndex == 1){
>
>     //Detecting whatever was under otherButtonTitles:
>     //Right now it's checking if the user clicked "Confirm" -> So here you can put whatever you need
>    NSLog(@"You clicked Confirm");
>
>       }
> ```
>
> }

Under the conditionals, you are checking which button the user is clicking.